# Does GNU Makefile support recursive invocations of .PHONY targets like "clean"?

Tags: makefile

I have a C/C++ project that is organized like this:

```
project
   |
   +---- c
   |     |
   |     +---- subproject1
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- bin
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- obj
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- src
   |     |
   |     +---- subproject2
   |               |
   |               +---- bin
   |               |
   |               +---- obj
   |               |
   |               +---- src
   |     
   +-----+ cpp
   |     |
   |     +---- subproject1
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- bin
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- obj
   |     |         |
   |     |         +---- src


  etcetera
```

At the `project` level, there's a Makefile that contains the following:

```
SUBDIRS = c cpp

all: $(SUBDIRS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

The `c` and `cpp` sub-directories contain similar Makefiles with different `SUBDIRS` definitions. Typing `make` at the command prompt from the `project`, `c` or `cpp` directories causes make to change directory to each sudb-directory in `SUBDIRS` and run make with that sub-directory's Makefile. This behaves exactly as described in the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion) and I'm very happy with it. The manual also states that you can add a target like clean after the `$@` and it will invoke that target in the sub-directory's Makefile. Also great, but what the manual doesn't give guidance on is what to do when `SUBDIRS` contains more than one sub-directory, as my `project` and `c` directories do. I'm going to give you the two methods that I know work and then I'll pose my question.

1. Add a target for each sub-directory in the `clean` target's recipe:

```
  clean:
      $(MAKE) -C c $@
      $(MAKE) -C cpp $@
```

2. Loop over each sub-directory in the `clean` target's recipe (basically the same as method 1, but easier to add more sub-projects to):

```
  clean:
      @for subdir in $(SUBDIRS); do $(MAKE) -C $$subdir $@; done
```

My question is, is there a way of achieving the above that requires using only existing GNU make constructs, something like this (which doesn't work btw):

```
$(SUBDIRS) clean:
    $(MAKE) -C c $@
```

Comment: I suggest to switch to using non-recursive makefiles approach. There is a good template library for that http://github.com/cppfw/prorab . Then you can declare multiple `clean::` targets in your subprojects and all of those will be invoked by `make clean`.

Comment: Autotools-derived makefiles use something very much like your approach (2), and to the best of my knowledge, all portable `make` mechanisms for what you describe depend on the recipe to handle executing each needed sub-`make`.  GNU make does have `foreach`, but that is no better for this particular purpose than your option (2).  In fact, I would personally prefer (2) over GNU-specific, harder to read `foreach`.

Comment: @igagis that is one hella sophisticated make environment, I'm going to avoid it now, but I will probably return to it when I need to solve more complex build issues

Comment: @John, I didn't know there was a `foreach` command. Good to know! I like option 2 too, though M. Pacalet's suggestion provides the all-make-command solution I was asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare per-directory phony clean targets and add them as pre-requisites of `clean`:

```
CLEANSUBDIRS = $(addprefix clean-,$(SUBDIRS))
.PHONY: clean $(CLEANSUBDIRS)
clean: $(CLEANSUBDIRS)
$(CLEANSUBDIRS): clean-%:
    $(MAKE) -C $* clean
```

Comment: Thanks Monsieur le Professeur, that worked like a charm. And 100% GNU make, as requested! If I'm interpreting your commands correctly, `$*` is substituted with what remains after 'clean-' is removed from the pre-requisite that invoked the `$(CLEANSUBDIRS)` rule. Is that right? I want to make sure I understand what's happening here.

Comment: For understanding the best place to look is the manual.  For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

Comment: Quite right MadScientist, I shouldn't have been so lazy. Now I see exactly how Renaud's solution is working